# UV unwrapping distorts parts of a mesh when imported from magicavoxel

Tags: materials, uv

I'm having a problem with trying to UV unwrap my model in blender after importing the .obj file from MagicaVoxel. The material is an image texture called "Palette". It's outputed when the MagicaVoxel's model is exported as .obj to give it the color. I think this is the problem,

Before unwrap:
[image]

After unwrap:
[image]

The reason I need to do this is so I can use the image texture in unity for my character.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? You have a correctly unwrapped model that already displays the texture after import. Why are you re-unwrapping, and why does it surprise you that it ruins the previous job?

Comment: I am guessing the MagicaVoxel unwrap just positions each face over the pixel color in the palette that the face is supposed to be.  Effective, but not very friendly to see the way the colored areas connect.  You might have some success leaving the existing uv map alone and creating a new uv map for a more traditional unwrap (do this in the Data section of the Properties window, under UV Maps).  You can use this new UV map for your new unwrap, and even bake the existing colors to it.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos I'm doing this because the mesh is gray when exported as FBX and imported into unity. I haven't unwrapped it in the first image, MagicaVoxel uses a png file to label it's cubes and color them accordingly. When you put the outputed image on the material as a texture it colors the mesh, but it isn't UV unwrapped. UV unwrapping so the material shows up on the mesh in unity is the problem